# Detect mouse direction with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, direction

I want to initiate an action when the user hovers a certain element, but only if the mouse was coming from below the element. i.e. the hover checks for the cursor's direction, and fires a function only if the direction was "up" (the cursor entered the element from below).

There's a similar post about jQuery hover with mouse direction, but I'm assuming there must be a simpler solution if I only need 'up' and 'down' rather than using the mouse position to determine every possible angle.

Comment: A link to the similar post would help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution will be:

```
var mY = 0;
var over = 0;
var direction = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').mousemove(function(e){
        if (over == 0) mY = e.pageY;
    });
    $('.my_element').bind('mouseover mousemove', function(e){
        over = 1;
        if (e.pageY < mY){
            direction = 'From Bottom';
        }else{
            direction = 'From Top';
        }

    });
    $('.my_element').bind('mouseout', function(){
        over = 0;
    });
});
```

It's just a quick one, hopefully it works for you...